# Performance of Pig in local mode vs mapreduce mode

Tags: performance, mapreduce, apache-pig, local

I have a Hadoop cluster with 3 nodes and 12 GB of data / 1.5 mid records . I understood that Pig can be run in local mode (for development purpose)  and in mapreduce mode.

For a little research project I am comparing processing times of running Pig in local and mapreduce mode. 
When doing performance measurements the processing time in local mode is much faster than in mapreduce mode. (My code consists of loading the data file using JsonLoader with a schema , filtering and dumping the result.)

Is there a rule of thumb when map reduce mode is faster than local mode ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how you've tuned the YARN cluster to accomodate your workload, or how large the files you're reading actually are.

In general, 12 GB is not enough data to warrant the use of Hadoop/Mapreduce, assuming Pig can do multi-processing on its own.

However, if the files are split amongst datanodes, and you have allocated enough resources to each of those 3 machines, then the job should complete faster than just one machine.

You could even further enhance runtimes by using Pig on Tez or Spark engines.